# React Render Components on Switch function

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to create a page that renders components based on a selection.  Here is the main page that would watch the for the change.

```
const data = [{ number: 0, text: 'Content Type' },  { number: 1, text: 'Content Publishing Status' },  { number: 2, text: 'Geo Locations' },  { number: 3, text: 'Tags' },  { number: 4, text: 'Change Reason' },
  { number: 5, text: 'Delievery Status' },  { number: 6, text: 'Content Record' }];


export default class ReqEngineAdmin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      adminSelect: 0,
    };
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    log.debug('updateding to :', nextState.adminSelect);
    return this.state.adminSelect !== nextState.adminSelect;
  }

  handleChange = (e, i, v) => {
    log.debug('in handle Change', v);
    this.setState(() => ({ adminSelect: v }));
  };

  render() {
    const selected = this.state.adminSelect;

    return (
      <div className={styles.bodyContent}>
        <MainHeader title="Requirements Engine Admin" />
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.adminSelect} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {data.map((d, i) =>
            <MenuItem key={`AdminSelect_${i + 1}`} value={d.number} primaryText={d.text} />
          )}
        </DropDownMenu>
        <Divder />
        <RenderPanel panelNo={selected} {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The page that would handle the switch currently looks like so:

```
const renderPanel = (props) => {
  switch (props.panelNo) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <div>
          <ContentTypePanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <ContentTypeTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        <div>
          <PubStatusPanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <PubStatusTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <div>
          <GeoLocationPanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <GeoLocationTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <div>
          <TagsPanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <TagsTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    case 4:
      return (
        <div>
          <ChangeReasonPanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <ChangeReasonTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    case 5:
      return (
        <div>
          <DelieveryStatusPanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <DelieveryStatusTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    case 6:
      return (
        <div>
          <ContentRecordPanel {...props} />
          <Divider />
          <ContentRecordTable {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

renderPanel.propTypes = {
  panelNo: PropTypes.number,
};
export default renderPanel;
```

I'm trying to just past the changed state, but I'm lost on a solution to get the page to render the new Components.

Comment: Does renderPanel not render anything or rendering null?

Comment: what console.log output do you get from handleChange, and shouldComponentUpdate ?

Comment: Instead of a `switch`, you can put components into an array, e.g. `const panels = [ContentTypePanel, PubStatusPanel...]`.  And then `const SelectedPanel = panels[props.panelNo];` and `<div> <SelectedPanel {...props} />`.

Comment: @D-reaper it renders the first set of components, onChange however, it fails on reconciliation.

Comment: @DavorinRuševljan I get the according to the value selected 0,1, 2... however, it fails on rendering the next components.

Comment: @Sulthan no luck. Just now no errors relating to rendering, but the components in the dom don't change.

Comment: @KevinReevers That was not a fix, just an advice to remove duplications in your code.

Comment: @Sulthan they're two different components. The first is a form panel the second is a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the `componentWillUpdate` method:

```
componentWillupdate(nextProps,nextState){
 this.selectedPanel(nextState.selected, nextProps)
}

selectPanel(panelNo,props) =>{
 switch(panelNo){
  case 1: 
   return (
      <div>
        <PubStatusPanel {...props} /> <Divider /> <PubStatusTable />
      </div>
    );}
...
 case 0:
  default:
    return (
      <div>
        <ContentTypePanel {...props} /> <Divider /> <ContentTypeTable />
      </div>
    );
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

What is `DropDownMenu`? 
You are binding a onChange method to it. When is it supposed to be triggered ?
The `handleChange` method binded is expecting 2 arguments that you don't pass.

I think the handleChange callback should be rather defined at the `MenuItem` level

```
<MenuItem 
    key={`AdminSelect_${i + 1}`} 
    value={d.number} 
    primaryText={d.text}
    onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
/>
```

Comment: change method is working, it's on reconciliation that is causing an error.

Comment: Also unfortunately, we're restricted to using [material-ui components](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu)

Comment: Ok I didn't get you were using material-ui components.

Comment: sorry about that.